# Export to Excel using ASP

Tags: excel, asp-classic

At the time of exporting to excel using ASP. After converting a column in text format single quote is visible in the excel file. how to hide this automatically ?

Comment: how are you exporting to Excel?

Answer (score 1):

You might be helped by setting the style of your cell to mso-number-format:"\@", but I'd have to see your code to know the exact problem.

I think you might find [Styling Excel cells with mso-number-format](http://www.netdominus.co.uk/knowledgebase/mod/resource/view.php?id=182) and [Generate Excel files in ASP Classic](http://www.crydust.be/blog/2009/03/02/generate-excel-files-in-asp-classic/) useful.

Answer (score 1):

When you export to excel, you could juste make a table with cell, and put your value into double quote. Excel will read it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Here's the library I use, to export data to Excel 2007 (.xlsx) files.

It lets you export any DataSet, DataTable or List<> directly into an Excel 2007 file, using one line of code.

It's completely free, and you can download the source code (and see how to use it) here:
http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/CSharp/ExportToExcel.htm